# Return value from website using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, yield

I am using scrapy in Python am trying to get a value from a website that is then used for an iteration. The issue I have is that it seems to only be possible to send requests over yield which makes it then impossible to get a value returned.

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']
    start_urls = ['url1', 'url2', ...]
    headers = ['id', 'name', 'description']
    pageNumber = 0 #tried to use a global variable but that doesn't really work because of the sub process.

    def start_requests(self):
        for su in self.start_urls:
            yield Request('http://url.com%s' % su,
                        self.parse_pageNumber)
            for i in range(pageNumber):
                page = su+str(pageNumber)
                yield Request('http://url.com' % page,
                    self.parse_matches)

    def parse_pageNumber(self, response):
        finds page number

    def.parse_matches(self, response):
        does everything else and returns items
```

any idea on how to get the page number without much additional work?

Comment: Maybe you want to put the for loop which yields request for the page numbers in the ``parse_pageNumber`` instead?

Comment: Then I wouldn't know which page number belongs to which page anymore though. I also would still have the same issue about not being able to access the number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use the `meta` dictionary. First, you create initial requests to get the page numbers, but keep the url of interest in the `meta` dict. Then you create a new request inside the `parse_pageNumber`, but this time keep the page number inside the `meta` data. You can then retreive the page number from the `parse_matches` response. You can do this because the `meta` is shallow copied from `Request` to `Response` for exactly this purpose. Your code could look like this:

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']
    start_urls = ['url1', 'url2', ...]
    headers = ['id', 'name', 'description']

    def start_requests(self):
        for su in self.start_urls:
            yield Request('http://url.com%s' % su,
                        self.parse_pageNumber,
                        meta = {'su': su}
                          )

    def parse_pageNumber(self, response):
        pageNumber = response.xpath('get_page_number_expression')
        su = response.meta['su']
        for i in range(pageNumber):
                page = su + str(pageNumber)
                yield Request('http://url.com' % page,
                    self.parse_matches, meta={'page_number':str(pageNumber)})

    def parse_matches(self, response):
        pageNumber = response.meta['page_number']
        # do everything else
```

An excerpt from the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) for a better understanding of `meta`:

> **meta**
>   A dict that contains arbitrary metadata for this request. This dict is empty for new Requests, and is usually populated by
>   different Scrapy components (extensions, middlewares, etc). So the
>   data contained in this dict depends on the extensions you have
>   enabled.
>   See Request.meta special keys for a list of special meta keys
>   recognized by Scrapy.
>   This dict is shallow copied when the request is cloned using the
>   copy() or replace() methods, and can also be accessed, in your spider,
>   from the response.meta attribute.

**Note:**
Although the `meta` approach is recommended, your case seems to be a bit simpler due to the fact that you are constructing your request URLs by directly using the page numbers, in which case, you could probably just use the `urlparse` module to extract this information from the `response.url` in the `parse_matches()` method. But still, `meta` is a more robust approach.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is exactly what I needed and you saved me from writing my own filters to get the page numbers without scrapy. Works fine :)